# Factorial calculation using fork() in C for Linux

Tags: c, linux, fork, children, factorial

I need to create a program that calculates the factorial number for one previously declared through *main* argument using fork()

Sorry for the printfs in portuguese, just ignore them, the point is to divide the number that was set on the arguments and make the calculation using two childrens, after that print the result using the father process. But I'm unable to proceed with the result i've got on the childrens, since they are different processes, can anyone help me solve this?

follows the code i've got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void filho_01();
void filho_02();

int num=0, total1=1,total2=1, cont=0,num2=0,valor,resultado=0;

int main(int agrc, char** argv) { 
    pid_t var1, var2;
    printf("Calculo de Fatorial com Fork \n\n");
    printf("Processo-Pai: Iniciando Execucao.\n\n");
    printf("Valor Obtido atraves do Parametro\n");

    num = atoi(argv[1]); 
    num2=num/2;
    valor=num;

    var1=fork();
    if ( var1 == 0 ) filho_01();
    var2=fork();
    if ( var2 == 0 ) filho_02();
    waitpid(var1,&total1,0);
    waitpid(var2,&total2,0);

    printf("%d",total1);
    resultado=total1*total2;


    printf("\nProcesso-Pai: Encerrando Execucao.\n");  
    printf(" \n   Fatorial de %d = %d \n",valor, resultado); 

}

void filho_01() {
printf("\n\n Filho 1 iniciando:\n");
printf("Calculando...\n");
sleep(3);


    for (cont = num; num >num2; num--) {    
        printf("  filho01: valor = %d \n", num);
        total1=total1*num;
    }

         exit(0);
}


void filho_02() {
printf("\n\n Filho 2 iniciando:\n");
printf("Calculando...\n");
sleep(5);


    for (cont = num2; num2 >=1; num2--) {    
        printf("  filho02: valor = %d \n", num2);
        total2=total2*num2;
    }
       exit(0);
}
```

Comment: No C but there is a C# in this forking factorials code golf. Also perl, java, other linux-friendly langs:  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/forking-factorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Children cannot modify their parent. In the children, the `total` variables are separate from the ones in the parent. You simply cannot communicate with the parent this way. Use explicit shared memory, or some other RPC mechanism.

Comment: On some platforms, the child's memory image is copy-on-write, so the difference may only be visible after you assign values to the copied cvariables. Depending on the memory representation, `&total1` might still have the same value (I guess?) but on most modern systems, printing that will reveal the difference.

Comment: Also, your use of `waitpid` is incorrect. The second argument will be overwritten by the child's exit code. You explicitly `exit(0)` in both children anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I get your point, but i'm not quite familiar with shared memory, this is a college work and i've never studied it, so i dont think i'm supposed to use it...

Comment: about the waitpid, that's when I tried to `exit(total1)` but it didn't work and i forgot to change it back

Comment: That would work, but only for small numbers (typically one byte, 0-255).

Comment: A straightforward RPC mechanism on Unix is the pipe. Have the child write its result (as a string, or a byte serialization) and the parent read it from the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

so after a few days i did it!
i did not comment the code 'cause i guess it is ease to understand
(sorry about that).
i did use pipe for process comunication.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int product = 1; // global scope variable

//  prototypes
int factorial(int, int);

int factorial(int start, int n) {
  int product_ = 1;
  
  for ( int i = start; i <= n; i++ ) {
    product_ *= i;
  }

  return product_;
}

int main( void ) {
    siginfo_t infop;
    pid_t firstSon, secondSon;
    __id_t fSon = firstSon, sSon_ = secondSon;
    int fd[2], n, fStatus, sStatus;
    int middle, factor;

    printf( "%s", "Enter a number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &n );

    if ( n < 2 ) {
        printf( "\nFactorial of %d is %s\n", n, "1" );
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if ( pipe( fd ) < 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "\nerror pipe" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    else if ( (firstSon = fork()) < 0 || (secondSon = fork()) < 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "\nfork error\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE  );
    }
    else if ( firstSon == 0 ) {
        middle = n / 2;
        factor = factorial( 1, middle );
        printf( "\n%s: %d", "First process result", factor );
        close( fd[0] );
        write( fd[1], &factor, sizeof( int ) );
    }
    else if ( secondSon == 0 ) {
        middle = n / 2 + 1;
        factor = factorial( middle, n );
        printf( "\n%s: %d", "Second process result", factor );
        close( fd[0] );
        write( fd[1], &factor, sizeof( int ) );
    }
    else {
        waitid(P_PID, fSon, &infop, WEXITED);
        close( fd[1] );
        read( fd[0], &factor, sizeof( int ) );
        product *= factor;
        waitid(P_PID, sSon_, &infop, WEXITED);
        close( fd[1] );
        read( fd[0], &factor, sizeof( int ) );
        product *= factor;
        printf( "\nFactorial of %d is %d\n", n, product );
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```